# TypeError: $(…).tooltip is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am getting

> TypeError: $(…).tooltip is not a function

error in the jquery file in which i am initialising tooltip() function while using lightbox2 with bootstrap.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      html: true
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> try this link and remove ur local url for bootstrap js

Comment: Is the bootstrap JS file loading?

Comment: check your console, is this `TypeError: $(…).tooltip is not a function` the only error you see?

Comment: maybe incorrect path to some js-library?

Comment: i have also tried cdn @ganesh but still not getting rid of this error

Comment: yes js file is loading @epascarello

Comment: this is the only error i see in console. @TheFlash everything else is working fine however i found a sloutionjust by removing the whole function from the main.js file and added to the index.php under script tags becuase i needed tooltip for only that page.

Comment: @Gagandeep You do not happen to have 2 versions of jQuery on the page?

Comment: No i dont have two versions on my page and it is 2.1.4 @epascarello :)

Answer (score 10):

This can happen when jQuery is included twice.

For people using Rails, jQuery is already included by default (check `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`):

```
//= require jquery
```

Including jQuery again, for example with a `<script>` tag in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, will result in this error.

The solution is to remove the `<script>` tag in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: @NeerajRana True, but this is common when starting to work with any framework.  The framework loads jQuery, and if you are integrating already-working code from another non-framework project, it is likely also including jQuery.  In my case, it happened when converting some non-Bootstrap pages to use Bootstrap.

Comment: I believe this happens when using a chat plugin like PureChat also. It loads its own JQuery. I believe that Bootstrap adds `.tooltip()` to the first (Rails) JQuery. Once the second JQuery is loaded, then you are using the second JQuery in your `$(document)` and `turbolinks:load` events. The second JQuery doesn't know about `.tooltip()`. By commenting out PureChat, the problem goes away. I'm going to test to verify the function exists before I call it with `if (typeof jqueryobject.tooltip === "function")`.

Comment: Oh man! This is the only time I've seen someone say this, and this was my issue. Ugh, what a stupidly simple thing. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

My favorite part of jQuery UI is `tooltip()`, and I often forget that it has not *always existed in jQuery UI*.  It was added for version 1.9...

> version added: 1.9 (Source: **[API.jQueryUI.com: Tooltip Widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**.)

If you don't have a version of jQuery UI at version 1.9 or higher, you'll get the error: `tooltip() is not a function()`.